# How can i customize the action of a RowAction in Prestashop AdminController?

Tags: php, prestashop

I overrided AdminCartRulesControllerCore and i added a Row Action to the AdminCartRulesController and that work fine.

```
$this->addRowAction('Generate');
```

But i don't know how to define the Action that will be called when i press "Generate". I Know that there is away to create link using :

```
public function displayGeneratetLink($token, $id, $name = null) {
    return '<a href="#" class="download" title="test"><i class="icon-cloud-upload"></i> ' . ($this->l('Export')) . '</a>';
}
```

In my case i don't need a redirection. I need a function that i can execute without any redirection.

Comment: PrestaShop version?

Comment: Prestashop  1.6 version

Answer (score 2):

The following example is to add a new action called 'approve' to the helper list:

You can add the following line of code in the constructor of your admin controller.

```
$this->addRowAction('approve');
```

Your initProcess() function should have following code:

```
public function initProcess()
    {
        parent::initProcess();
        if (Tools::getIsset('approve' . $this->table)) {
            $this->action = 'approveAction';
        }
    }
```

Then you have to define a function named processApproveAction() in the same controller.

```
public function processApproveAction()
{
--- YOUR CODE HERE ---
}
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: Hi, thank you for your comment, I tried this but i did not see the option "aprove" in the list of Row Action (Edit, Remove).

Comment: In that case, there must be a problem with the Helper List you have generated as this is all we have to do to make is work and I have done it in many of my modules.

Comment: here the same, i can't see the new action link

Comment: where sould i declare helper list in my module ?

Answer (score 1):

You can do your own action column.

You should include a row identifier field in your `select`:

```
$this->_select = ' a.id_order AS id_pdf';
```

Then, you can include this new field in your `field list`:

```
$this->fields_list = array(
            /*other fields here*/
            'id_pdf' => array(
                'title' => $this->l('Actions'),
                'width' => 35,
                'align' => 'center',
                'callback' => 'printPDFIcons',
                'orderby' => false,
                'search' => false,
                'remove_onclick' => true)
        );
```

Finally you must implement your `printPDFIcons` function. $id_order will be your identifier and $tr is an array with all your row data:

```
    public function printPDFIcons($id_order, $tr)
    {
        $route_to_pdf = 'for example: route to a pdf file to download it';
        if ($route_to_pdf)
            return '<span class="btn-group-action">
                        <span class="btn-group">
                            <a class="btn btn-default" target="_blank" title="' . $this->l('Label PDF') . '" href="' . $route_to_pdf . '">
                                <i class="icon-print"></i>
                            </a>
                        </span>
                    </span>';
        else
            return '';
    }
```

If you want to execute some action when you click in your custom button you should display a link to the own `AdminController` and pass as `Action` parameter some identifier like `Generate`. Then use `postProcess` function to execute your specific code.

Good luck.

Comment: Thanks for the effort it's clear. Bu in my case i'm not looking for a way to execute action without using any link (href).